# Mackey theory in the setting of locally profinite groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, profinite-groups

Is there an analogue of [1, Thm. 10.23] for ordinary smooth representations of a locally profinite group (l.p.g. for short)?

I have already checked introductory chapters of some classical references in ordinary smooth representation theory of l.p.g.'s [2, 3, 4] but without success.

The closest hint I was given seems to be the general discussion in [5, Sec. 5.5], but unfortunately I cannot access it freely on the Internet or in any library from my university. Thank you in advance.

**Bibliography**

[1] C. W. CURTIS AND I. REINER, *Representation Theory of Finite Groups
and Associative Algebras*, John Wiley and Sons Inc, 1962.

[2] C. J. BUSHNELL AND G. HENNIART, *The Local Langlands Conjecture for GL(2)*, Springer, 2006.

[3] W. CASSELMAN, *Introduction to the theory of admissible representations of p-adic reductive groups* (1974), Preprint, University of British Columbia.

[4] I.N. BERNSTEIN AND A.V. ZELEVINSKY, *Representations of the group GL(n, F)
where F is a local non-archimedean field*, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk 31 (1976), 5–70.

[5] M.-F. VIGNÉRAS, *Représentations l-modulaires d'un groupe réductif p-adique avec l $\neq$ p*, Progress in Math. 137, Birkhaüser, 1996.

Comment: Crossposted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343643/